# Focus HEAD initially in git log

Tags: git, pager, git-log

I use this command to view my Git commit graph:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Is there a way to have `git log` focus on the `HEAD` pointer initially? As in: put the `HEAD` commit in the middle of the screen when I run this command, while still showing the whole tree?

I often have lots of other commits on top of me so, in almost every case, when I run this command, the first thing I do is search for "`\(HEAD`". It's annoying...

Is there a way to automate that initial search in `less`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

less take an argument for initial search. You could use it when declaring pager.

Example using GIT_PAGER environment variable:

```
GIT_PAGER='less -p"\(HEAD"' git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

You could also set pager with this option as global pager config or project pager config.

Comment: I think `less`'s `-p` flag is the way to go. However, you should probably save the initial value of `GIT_PAGER` to some other variable and reset the value after running that `git log` command. You could also define a Git alias to automate all that.